# Why this instagram image url not working with HTML img tag

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

Why Instagram image URL does not work with HTML `<img>` tag?

```html
<img src='https://instagram.fjai3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/273154298_119474150437980_8801290709408392534_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_p1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.fjai3-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=7w4ERevjerIAX8hhoMk&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9CrFcW-JrAfkLLgdIRlVlnE7lc0KspmLJDpPPy3CgP_Q&oe=62200913&_nc_sid=83d603' alt='scraped URL'>
```

but it is perfectly opening in the new tab.

Answer (score 7):

You can see error in your console: `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200`. That's because response with the image has `cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin` header. It means it works only on same origin (domain). Browser blocked it.

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Globally? No. That's up to the server owner. The most you can do is [disable CORS protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) in **your own browser**.

Answer (score -3):

Because there is nothing inside the tag, it has nothing to parse

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Provide details.